# Avoid self closing tag - Biztalk envelope schema

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

Below my XSLT call template, I want to avoid self closing tag while the value is empty.

If there is no value the output of Error tag is :

```
<ns0:Error />
```

However I would like to get the output as

```
<ns0:Error></ns0:Error>
```

Comment: Correcting my question: I want to avoid self closing tag while the value is empty. If there is no value the output of Error tag is :<ns0:Error/ > However I would like to get the output as <ns0:Error> </ns0:Error>

Comment: Your correction is not clear: do you want your output elements to have a space character instead of being empty?

Comment: Is this being done as an inline call template scripting functoid in a BizTalk map, or is it being done completely in custom XSLT?  Also, could you give a little more inforation about why you have this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you have is to change the output method to 'html', this should prevent self closing tags:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
```

If that's not an option as the output is not html which I assume it's not from you example then you might want to trick the XSLT by adding blank content into your elements.

```
<xsl:variable name="blank" select="''"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$blank"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This *may* work with some processors (e.g. libxslt) but not with others (Xalan, Saxon).